# PHP или Python

Tags: python, php

Добрый день!
Думаю начать изучать Python (в будущем собираюсь программировать на нем)
И решил сделать несколько виджетов (либо скачать и подкорректировать под себя)
Но не нашел ни одной книжки про программирование на Python под web.
Считаю что придется выучить PHP и потом сопоставлять с Python, ибо по-другому никак.
Прошу убедить в обратном :-)
Заранее спасибо!
Bloodskys.

Comment: Я не считаю что нужно вообще учить подобные языки для начала. Вам будет трудно пересесть на такие языки как Java , C , C++ ( а они вам понадобятся если вы будете этим заниматься профессионально ). Это относится только к тому если вы только начинаете программировать :).

Comment: В будущем я и не собирался переходить на java и C, так как многие хорошие программисты Python говорят (считают, доказывают) что средствами Python можно сделать все то же что и средствами C, вот только кода меньше и он проще.
C++, C любят начинающие, "молятся" на него, отстаивают его, хотя даже не пытались почитать, сравнить с другими языками...
Так что, к сожалению, людей, без оснований говорящих, что лучше учить C и что он более перспективен, я просто не воспринимаю...

Comment: Вы ОЧЕНЬ сильно заблуждаетесь - это от незнания.У вас ещё нет даже понятия что такое язык Си, чтобы не воспринимать других кто его любит.Python не панацея.И уж тем более не настолько универсальный язык чтобы на нём всё решать.Какие-то технологии гораздо удобнее использовать для определённых ситуаций.Просто про, знают какие ЯП юзать для конкретных задач.

Comment: Согласен с @GenchiK .

Comment: вот так почитаешь и других и думаешь, что все выросли на ассемблере, и отстаивают его крутость. Но в реальности, вот прямо сейчас, для *программистов* предоставляется 'простой' интерфейс(java, c++, python и др., менее распространённые яп), для той же самой работы, что можно сделать и на С и на Ассемблере, но с гораздо меньшим усилием и временными затратами. Но понимание, для чего нужен каждый интерфейс - нужно. Есть даже антишаблон проектирования, при котором для поставленного задания выбирается яп, на котором решить поставленные вопросы не предоставляется возможным(либо затруднительным)

Answer (score 2):

[Книга по Питону](http://rghost.ru/36710285)

---

Начните с нее. Довольна подброная. Она именно про язык, а не про веб. После освоения Питона лезте в документацию Django. По поводу PHP vs Python: я вообще php-разработчик, потом когда почитал про питон и руби, пожалел, что мой выбор изначально пал на ПыХу, собираюсь перепрофилироваться :)

Answer (score 0):

Python - язык программирвоания не для веба исключительно, на нём можно писать практически всё, а в вебе его используют потому что он просто хороший язык. Для веба нжно спользовать web-фреймворки на питоне, к примеру Django - вот с него и начинайте. Хотя понимать как работает питон всё равно нужно.

Comment: Эхх.. На вопрос ответа так и не прозвучало..
Вопрос заключается в следующем:
Не нашел нормальных книжек подобных "PHP для новичков", только о Python.
Те книги, которые читаю - все о программировании не под веб.
Так что? Учить PHP и проводить аналогии с Pyhton самому, или есть у кого какие материалы для изучения сразу "web-Python"?

Comment: С такой постановкой вопроса - да, учить PHP...

Comment: Начните читать отсюда http://docs.python.org/
По джанге все написано тут https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/
Есть еще замечательный фреймворк Pyramid, почитать можно тут http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/

Answer (score 0):

Вообще не советую начинать с Питона. (хотя сам являюсь ярым его фанатом и разработчиком).  Начните с Пхп, он просто для веба, для простых задач.  После того как почувствуете опору, стоит взглянуть на другие языки. 
Если начнете с Питона, могут возникнуть трудности, которых при разработки на пхп не будет.

А если аы хотите стать специалистом, то вам неприменно придется глянуть и Си и Ассемблер .. Увы, без этого никуда.

Выбирайте пхп, если мало опыта!.

Answer (score 0):

Зависит на самом деле от задачи. Я лично использую PHP для веб ибо в данной отрасли он очень удобен. Python - как инструмент для автоматизации и тех проектов, которые надо решить "Вот прям сейчас надо" ибо он очень простой в написании.

Comment: Не стоит тратить время на такие «холиварные» вопросы вроде «какой язык лучше для Х». Они долго не живут, а в последнее время ещё и минусы привлекают. :)

Comment: Верно сказано .

Answer (score -1):

Официальная документация лучше во всего, во всем!